# Kivy position of a GridLayout's children always returns (0,0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

When I add some element to my GridLayout, if want to get the element postion, Kivy always returns (0,0), but it not true, because the elements are correctly positioned on my windows.

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.text = 'hello'

def add_sources(self, sources):
    print(self.pos) #(0,0), but is not (0,0)
    self.add_widget(Label(text='foo', pos=self.pos))
```

And this is my main class.

```
class MyClass(Widget):

my_layout = ObjectProperty(GridLayout())

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.load_layout()

def load_map(self):
    self.my_layout.rows = 2
    self.my_layout.cols = 2
    self.draw_ui()

def draw_ui(self):
    a = ImageButton()
    b = ImageButton()
    c = ImageButton()
    d = ImageButton()

    self.my_layout.add_widget(a)
    self.my_layout.add_widget(b)
    self.my_layout.add_widget(c)
    self.my_layout.add_widget(d)

    a.add_sources(0)
    b.add_sources(1)
    c.add_sources(0)
    d.add_sources(1)
```

Why getting the widget's position returns me (0,0)? What am I doing wrong?

This is what I get:

[image: I'm getting this]

But I want the "foo" string in front of each "hello" string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pos is equal to [0,0] at the first frame of the kivy GUI loop, when you print it. It changes a bit later. You have two ways of solving this problem:

1. Wait till the second frame, when pos is updated as expected.
2. Bind the pos instead of just assigning it once at the beginning.

Solution 1) example:

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    ...
    @mainthread
    def add_sources(self, sources):
        self.add_widget(Label(text='foo', pos=self.pos))
```

Solution 2) example:

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    ...
    def add_sources(self, sources):
        self.add_widget(Label(text='foo', pos=self.setter('pos')))
```